# List pdf Attachments using PDFBox (Java)

Tags: java, apache, pdf, nullpointerexception, pdfbox

I'd like to **get** all **filenames of attachments/embedded files of a PDF document**. I've been searching for a long time now, but my code still doesn't work.

What I tried:

```
File input = new File(inputfile); // Input File Path, Given as param from args[]
pd = PDDocument.load(input);
PDDocumentNameDictionary names = new PDDocumentNameDictionary(pd.getDocumentCatalog());
PDEmbeddedFilesNameTreeNode efTree = names.getEmbeddedFiles();
Map<String, COSObjectable> existedNames = efTree.getNames();

System.out.println(existedNames);//Print Embedded-Filenames to console
pd.close();
```

I don't know if it is even possible to print the content of a MAP to console. I'm coding in eclipse which doesn't give me any errors. But when I run the jar File I get always: `NullPointerException at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.getDocumentCatalog(PDDocument.java:778)`

Any ideas or help? Many thanks...

Comment: PDDocument.load() probably fails and returns null

Comment: PDDocument.load() works. I know because I'm doing other stuff with "pd" before... Something with the next 3 Lines (after loading pd = ...) must be wrong :/

Comment: On several examples i saw `Map<String, PDComplexFileSpecification> existedNames = efTree.getNames();` but when I change this in eclipse it gives me an error: `Type mismatch: Cannot convert from Map<String, COSObjectable> to Map<String, PDComplexFileSpecification>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution. For anyone with the same problem, the following code worked for me:

```
PDDocument pd;

File input = new File(inputfile); // Input File

pd = PDDocument.load(input);

//Writes all embedded Filenames (from pdf document) into Logfile
try{
    PDDocumentCatalog catalog = pd.getDocumentCatalog();
    PDDocumentNameDictionary names = catalog.getNames();
    PDEmbeddedFilesNameTreeNode embeddedFiles = names.getEmbeddedFiles();
    Map<String, COSObjectable> embeddedFileNames = embeddedFiles.getNames();

    //For-Each Loop is used to list all embedded files (if there is more than one)          
    for (Map.Entry<String, COSObjectable> entry : embeddedFileNames.entrySet())
    {   
        //You might need to configure the logger first
        logger.info("Inputfile: " + inputfile +"Found embedded File: " + entry.getKey() + ":");
    }

}
catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("Document has no attachments. ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [ExtractEmbeddedFiles example](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/ExtractEmbeddedFiles.java) from the source code download:

```
public final class ExtractEmbeddedFiles
{
    private ExtractEmbeddedFiles()
    {
    }

    /**
     * This is the main method.
     *
     * @param args The command line arguments.
     *
     * @throws IOException If there is an error parsing the document.
     */
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {
        if( args.length != 1 )
        {
            usage();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            PDDocument document = null;
            try
            {
                File pdfFile = new File(args[0]);
                String filePath = pdfFile.getParent() + System.getProperty("file.separator");
                document = PDDocument.load(pdfFile );
                PDDocumentNameDictionary namesDictionary = 
                        new PDDocumentNameDictionary( document.getDocumentCatalog() );
                PDEmbeddedFilesNameTreeNode efTree = namesDictionary.getEmbeddedFiles();
                if (efTree != null)
                {
                    Map<String, PDComplexFileSpecification> names = efTree.getNames();
                    if (names != null)
                    {
                        extractFiles(names, filePath);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        List<PDNameTreeNode<PDComplexFileSpecification>> kids = efTree.getKids();
                        for (PDNameTreeNode<PDComplexFileSpecification> node : kids)
                        {
                            names = node.getNames();
                            extractFiles(names, filePath);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // extract files from annotations
                for (PDPage page : document.getPages())
                {
                    for (PDAnnotation annotation : page.getAnnotations())
                    {
                        if (annotation instanceof PDAnnotationFileAttachment)
                        {
                            PDAnnotationFileAttachment annotationFileAttachment = (PDAnnotationFileAttachment) annotation;
                            PDComplexFileSpecification fileSpec = (PDComplexFileSpecification) annotationFileAttachment.getFile();
                            PDEmbeddedFile embeddedFile = getEmbeddedFile(fileSpec);
                            extractFile(filePath, fileSpec.getFilename(), embeddedFile);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            finally
            {
                if( document != null )
                {
                    document.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void extractFiles(Map<String, PDComplexFileSpecification> names, String filePath) 
            throws IOException
    {
        for (Entry<String, PDComplexFileSpecification> entry : names.entrySet())
        {
            String filename = entry.getKey();
            PDComplexFileSpecification fileSpec = entry.getValue();
            PDEmbeddedFile embeddedFile = getEmbeddedFile(fileSpec);
            extractFile(filePath, filename, embeddedFile);
        }
    }

    private static void extractFile(String filePath, String filename, PDEmbeddedFile embeddedFile)
            throws IOException
    {
        String embeddedFilename = filePath + filename;
        File file = new File(filePath + filename);
        System.out.println("Writing " + embeddedFilename);
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try
        {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(embeddedFile.toByteArray());
        }
        finally
        {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(fos);
        }
    }

    private static PDEmbeddedFile getEmbeddedFile(PDComplexFileSpecification fileSpec )
    {
        // search for the first available alternative of the embedded file
        PDEmbeddedFile embeddedFile = null;
        if (fileSpec != null)
        {
            embeddedFile = fileSpec.getEmbeddedFileUnicode(); 
            if (embeddedFile == null)
            {
                embeddedFile = fileSpec.getEmbeddedFileDos();
            }
            if (embeddedFile == null)
            {
                embeddedFile = fileSpec.getEmbeddedFileMac();
            }
            if (embeddedFile == null)
            {
                embeddedFile = fileSpec.getEmbeddedFileUnix();
            }
            if (embeddedFile == null)
            {
                embeddedFile = fileSpec.getEmbeddedFile();
            }
        }
        return embeddedFile;
    }

    /**
     * This will print the usage for this program.
     */
    private static void usage()
    {
        System.err.println( "Usage: java " + ExtractEmbeddedFiles.class.getName() + " <input-pdf>" );
    }
}
```

Comment: I know the example code, but it doesn't work for me. My code is also based on this sample.

Comment: @Nicola please upload the pdf file. Btw what version are using? 2.0.0?

Comment: @Nicola If you are using an 1.8 version, make sure that you're checking whether the file is encrypted. Or use loadNonSeq() instead of load().

Comment: I'm using pdfbox-app-1.8.11.jar. I'm already checking if the pdf Files are encrypted (isEncrypted()). My pdf contains the following attachments: 1.docx, 2.doc, 3.xlsx. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: And are they encrypted? Can you upload them somewhere? Or send them to tilman at snafu dot de.